# python - issues with pdfquery load

Tags: python, pdf

I'm using pdfquery library in python in order to extract text. To do so i load the pdf, and until now it always work.
But when i tried to work with the [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sbx6hkyqrg7i7zi/AABgL_BvjcEwZh3GBRs9_l_8a?dl=0) i faced the following problem:

When i run the code:

```
import pdfquery
pdfQuery = pdfquery.PDFQuery('10241.pdf')
pdfQuery.load()
```

The program seems to stuck and never finish.

Has anyone faced this problem, or have any suggestions how to overcome it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How many pages your PDF has?

It could be helpful to specify the number of pages to load:

```
pdfQuery.load(0)
```

The above code will just load the first page and save time.

Comment: Is it just PDFQuery being so slow or other libraries are the same?